# Using buttons to scroll dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to use 'up' and 'down' buttons to scroll through options. Ultimately, the actual dropdown list will be hidden from the user. This example I have left it visible. I can't use `onclick` in the `button` tag because this will be a Chrome Extension. The issue is the buttons don't seem to do anything.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
    document.getElementById('d').addEventListener('click', theme(this));
    document.getElementById('u').addEventListener('click', theme(this));
});
var ddl = document.getElementById("s")
function theme(x) {
  if (x.value === 'down') {
    ddl.selectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex + 1
  } else {
    ddl.selectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex - 1
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="s">
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
    <option>Lizard</option>
    <option>Snake</option>   
</select>
    <button id="d" type="button" value="up">up</button>
    <button id="u" type="button" value="down">down</button>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with this bit `addEventListener('click', theme(this));`. You think it will call `theme(this)` when you click the button and `this` will be the button you clicked on. But first, `this` in this context is `window` not the button and second, `theme(this)` is called immediately when `addEventListener` is executed, and as it doesn't return anything you don't attach any event listeners. Try this instead:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('d').addEventListener('click', () => theme('up'));
    document.getElementById('u').addEventListener('click',() => theme('down'));
});
var ddl = document.getElementById("s")
function theme(x) {
  if (x === 'down') {
    ddl.selectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex + 1
  } else if(ddl.selectedIndex > 0){
      ddl.selectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex - 1
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="s">
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
    <option>Lizard</option>
    <option>Snake</option>   
</select>
    <button id="d" type="button" value="up">up</button>
    <button id="u" type="button" value="down">down</button>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the explanation as well. How do I avoid clicking 'Up' and leaving the dropdown in a 'blank' state?

Comment: Just add a check to make sure the current index is above 0, I updated the snippet